# Deploy finished jsf application on glassfish server

Tags: java, glassfish, war

I have built a JSF application and used a local glassfish server on my computer and I have developed in NetBeans.

Now I feel finished and want to try to install the JSF applicationen on a non local glassfish server.

I have set up a glassfish server on a Winows 2008 machine and everything seems to work as it should.

But I have no idea how I will deploy my JSF code on the server, do I need to package it in some way?

Have tried googling but have not found a good answer so if someone could guide me I would be grateful.

I use:

glassfish 3.1.2

Windows 2008

JSF 2.1

NetBeans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your glassfish server using the command

```
asadmin start-domain yourdomain
```

Then go to the administration GUI:

```
http://localhost:4848
```

Under the point `Applications` you can deploy and activate your web projects.

To deploy your jsf-application you have to export it as a `war`-file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now I have an idea how I'll do, I'll try and see how it goes

Answer (score 2):

`But I have no idea how I will deploy my JSF code on the server` => **you can't deploy a code o web server directly**
You need to make war file of you web app (jsf is a web app) and after than upload in glassfish via web admin console
You can see a [detailed blog with pictures here as how can you deploy war](http://blog.eviac.com/2012/08/how-to-deploy-war-file-using-glassfish.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll follow the guide and see how it goes